# Error using tensorflow Graph Def can not be larger than 2GB

Tags: image, classification

I'm using inception v3 model imageNet shape with tensorflow for image classification. The program is designed to classify a single image so I tried to modify it to classify a test image database. It classifies the images well but arrives at about 20 images it returns me the following error:`File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1912, in as_graph_def
    raise ValueError("GraphDef cannot be larger than 2GB.")
ValueError: GraphDef cannot be larger than 2GB.`

Below the image label code that I modified:

```
        # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import os, sys
import time
import tensorflow as tf

def chargement_image(path):
    image = []
    image = os.listdir(path)

    return image 

resultat = []
best = []
nbr = 0
som = 0
os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '2'

start_time = time.time()

# Chargement de la base de test
test_path = sys.argv[1]

list_img = chargement_image(test_path)
for i in range(len(list_img)):
    image_path = test_path+list_img[i]

# Read in the image_data
    image_data = tf.gfile.FastGFile(image_path, 'rb').read()

# Loads label file, strips off carriage return
    label_lines = [line.rstrip() for line 
                   in tf.gfile.GFile("retrained_labels.txt")]

# Unpersists graph from file
    with tf.gfile.FastGFile("retrained_graph.pb", 'rb') as f:
        graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
        graph_def.ParseFromString(f.read())
        tf.import_graph_def(graph_def, name='')

    with tf.Session() as sess:
    # Feed the image_data as input to the graph and get first prediction
        softmax_tensor = sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name('final_result:0')

        predictions = sess.run(softmax_tensor, \
             {'DecodeJpeg/contents:0': image_data})
        #print(len(predictions))
    # Trier pour afficher les étiquettes de la première prédiction par ordre de bon taux de classement
        top_k = predictions[0].argsort()[-len(predictions[0]):][::-1]
        #print(top_k)

        for node_id in top_k:
            human_string = label_lines[node_id]
            score = predictions[0][node_id]
        resultat.append(score)
            print('%s (score = %.5f)' % (human_string, score))
        #print(score)

    nbr += 1
    best.append(resultat[0])
    del resultat[:]
    #print(best)
    print(nbr)
    print("=========================================")
#print(best)
#print(nbr)
for i in range(len(best)):
    som += best[i]
taux_precision = float(100. * som / nbr)
print 'Precision: ' + str(taux_precision) + '%'
print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to put below line outside the for loop:

```
# Loads label file, strips off carriage return
label_lines = [line.rstrip() for line 
               in tf.gfile.GFile("retrained_labels.txt")]

# Unpersists graph from file
with tf.gfile.FastGFile("retrained_graph.pb", 'rb') as f:
    graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
    graph_def.ParseFromString(f.read())
    tf.import_graph_def(graph_def, name='')
```